# Java Matrix multiplication ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception, multiplication

Just started learning Java by my own and i am trying to do different programs i get in college from C++ into Java. 
I wanted to do a multiplication of matrices using some void methods but i am constantly getting this exception (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) when trying to multiply matrices like 2-2 2-1,
3-2 2-3, etc. The program works for matrices like 3-3 3-3, 4-4 4-4 but it fails when the variables are not the same. Can't understand where i got it wrong, can anybody help?

Ty

import java.util.Scanner;
public class MultiplicationOfMatrixes {

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int n,m,k;
    System.out.println("The number of lines of the first matrix is");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The number of rows of the first matrix and the number of lines of the second matrix is ");
    m = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The number of rows of the second matrix is ");
    k = sc.nextInt();

    double a[][] = new double[n][m];
    double b[][] = new double[m][k];
    double c[][] = new double[n][k];        

    read(a, n, m);
    read(b, m, k);

    multiply(a,b,c,n,m,k);

    write(c,n,k);
}

public static void read (double v[][], int q, int r)
{
    System.out.printf("\nThe numbers for the matrix are \n ");
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    for(j=0;j<r;j++)
    {
        System.out.printf(" On the position %d %d%n ", i, j);
        v[i][j] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
}

public static void multiply (double v[][], double w[][], double u[][], int q, int r, int z)
{
    int i, j, t;
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    for(j=0;j<r;j++)
    {

        for(t=0;t<z;t++)
        u[i][t] = u[i][t] + v[i][t]*w[t][j]; 
    }

}

public static void write (double v[][], int q, int r)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    for(j=0;j<r;j++)
    {
        System.out.printf("c[%d][%d]= %f%n", i, j, v[i][j]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When you have a problem like this, it's always a good idea to post the entire stack trace of the error you are getting.

Comment: Yea obviously, Nobody wants to trace an error through 3182931 lines of code. Sorry about that.                                                          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at MultiplicationOfMatrixes.multiply(MultiplicationOfMatrixes.java:48)
 at MultiplicationOfMatrixes.main(MultiplicationOfMatrixes.java:23)

Comment: w[t][j] is out of the bound, the t < k, but w[].lenght is m. I dont' remember multiplication of arrays so I will not check your code. I am sure it is an excercies but if not then apache math provides impelemntations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u[i][t] = u[i][t] + v[i][j]*w[j][t] seems to be working for me.

You put in the wrong numbers for the arrays. v is declared by the first two numbers, and is therefore only defined by i and j. w is defined by the second two, and is therefore declared by j and t. Additionally, this always adds together the numbers where the i and t define the matrix slot you're going into, and the j is the same in both matrices.

Edit: The top line of code being the line that is put into public static void multiply.